# Loop-the-loop problem - Horizontal and Vertical forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, free-body-diagram

Problem: A small marble of mass m and radius r rolls without slipping along the loop-the-loop track (pic attached). If it starts from rest at a height of 6R above the bottom (R =radius of the circular part of the track), what is the force (horizontal and vertical components) acting on it at the point Q.

I was able to find the horizontal component.

The vertical component in my opinion should be mg but looks like correct answer is (5/7)mg. Can someone please show how?

Also, which force is responsible for providing the horizontal force (i.e. centripetal force)

[image]

Comment: Think about the condition that keeps the ball rolling.

Answer (score 1):

If the marble rolls without slipping, then there is a (static) friction force which provides the torque required for angular acceleration. At point Q the marble is losing linear and angular velocity, so the friction force is directed upward.  The centripetal force comes from the normal force at the surface.  Don't forget that the radius of motion for the center of mass is (R – r).